# Find the semester with a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query :

```
SELECT * FROM `commande`:

id   datecreation            motif          tva    numero   periode
1   27/02/2017 16:16    Achat marchandise   NULL    C001    NULL
9   28/03/2017 14:43    Achat marchandise   NULL    C002    NULL
10  28/03/2017 14:47    Achat marchandise   NULL    C003    NULL
11  28/04/2017 14:53    Achat marchandise   NULL    C004    NULL
12  28/04/2017 14:57    Achat marchandise   NULL    C005    NULL
13  28/05/2017 15:00    Achat marchandise   NULL    C006    NULL
14  28/05/2017 15:36    Achat marchandise   NULL    C007    NULL
15  28/05/2017 16:58    Achat marchandise   NULL    C008    NULL
16  28/05/2017 17:11    Achat marchandise   NULL    C009    NULL
```

I want to create a stored procedure to update a column "periode"  according to "datecreation" month,"periode" column is a semester number,

for example:

```
 if month(datecreation)=4 then periode = 2 

 if month(datecreation)=3 then periode = 1

 if month(datecreation)=5 then periode = 2
```

How I can do this?Thanks

Comment: On what basis Is `month=3` is `1` and for `4` and `5` it is `2`?

Comment: A semester means that the year is divided into 2 parts. A quarter system means 4 parts, which is closer to your requirement. Can you confirm if you want semester or quarter.

Comment: How? How is 4th and 5th month as periode 2?

Comment: On what basis Is month=3 is 1 and for 4 and 5 it is 2?  Yes that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment semester system divides year in 2 parts. In that case month 1 - 6 are semester 1 and month 7 - 12 are semester 2. You can achieve it like below

```
update commande
set periode =
(floor(month(datecreation)/6) + 1 );
```

If you want month 3 as `1` and month `4` and `5` as `2`, then you are talking about quarter system where year is divided in 4 parts. In that case use

```
update commande
set periode =
(floor(month(datecreation)/4) + 1 );
```